# QTableWidget having multiples lines in cell

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I'm using a `QTableWidget` for a simple table. Now each cell should contain two numbers, but I don't want them to be left to right, but for readability on top of each other. I'm using Qt 5.8.

Hence, I tried something like this:

```
QTableWidget* table=new QTableWidget;
auto item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString("%1\n%2").arg(1).arg(2));
table->setItem(0, 0, item);
```

Interestingly, the outcome was that the newline `\n` was completely ignored. I obtain a cell containing 12. Replacing `\n` by `<br>` didn't helped.

Any idea, what I'm doing wrong/missing?

Answer (score 2):

This should work, just try to resize the height of your row to give the item enough space.

Comment: That worked! :-) Any idea how to resize automatically?

Comment: Have a look at [QTableView::resizeRowsToContent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#resizeRowsToContents).